# How to get Test Step from Allure Annotation (@Step)

Tags: java, maven, appium, allure

Currently we are workin in Appium Grid with maven and leantesting as our defect management tools.
We want to push to the leantesting if we found bugs automatically from jenkins.
We need parameter test step that we have before from @Step annotation.
Does anybody know how to get test step in string so we can pass through this as a parameter?

Thank you

Comment: What exactly do you need? Get the failed step name from runtime am I right?

Comment: I want get all steps in all methods in one TC with @Step anotation.           for exampe : @Step("Go To Filter Page")
 public FilterPage clickFilter(){
  clickElement(getIdLocator(filterButtonID));
  return new FilterPage(driver);
 }
 
 @Step("Go To Sort Button")
 private void clickSortPage(){
  clickElement(getIdLocator(sortButton));
 }  I want get step annotation into a string

Comment: It is still not clear what do you want? Get @Step annotation value as string nad store it somewhere?